# Interpolation Capability of Deep Neural Networks of bounded height

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, neural-networks

The Universal Approximation Theorem shows that deep neural networks can approximate any function in $C(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}^n)$ uniformly on compacts.  I'm curious, can the collection of a neural networks with bounded height *interpolate* any finite set of points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if neural networks are universal, then they can also interpolate finite sets of samples.

**Theorem:**
Let $\varrho: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an activation function $\varrho: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that DNNs of height $L \in \mathbb N$ are universal. Then for every set of points $(x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^N \subset \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R$, there exists a neural network $\Phi$ of depth $L$ such that $\Phi(x_i) = y_i$ for all $i = 1, \dots, N$.

*Proof.* Let $(x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^N \subset  K \times \mathbb R \subset \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R$, where $K$ is compact. By the Urysohn lemma, there exist $N$ continuous functions $(f_i)_{i=1}^N\subset C(\mathbb R^d, \mathbb R)$ such that $f_i(x_j) = \delta_{ij}$, for all $i,j \in  \{ 1, \dots, N\}$.

Since the set of invertible matrices is open, there exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that every matrix $(a_{i,j})_{i,j =1}^N$ with $|a_{i,j} - \delta_{i,j}| < \epsilon $, for all $i,j \in \{1, \dots, N\}$, is invertible.

Since, by assumption, we have that DNNs with activation function $\varrho$ are universal, there exist neural networks $(\Phi_{i})_{i=1}^N$ such that 
$$
|\Phi_{i}(x_j) - f_i(x_j)| = |\Phi_{i}(x_j) - \delta_{ij}| < \epsilon.
$$
Let $A = (a_{i,j})_{i,j =1}^N \in \mathbb R^{N \times N}$ be defined by 
$$
a_{i,j} := \Phi_{i}(x_j).
$$
Then $A^{-1}$ exists. We define a new network 
$$
\Phi : = [y_{1}, \dots, y_N] \cdot A^{-1} \left( \begin{array}{c} \Phi_1 \\ \Phi_2 \\ \vdots \\ \Phi_N\end{array} \right).
$$
It holds that $\Phi$ has $L$ layers, because each of the $\Phi_i$ had $L$ layers and we have not applied $\varrho$ again. Per definition, we have that 
$$
A^{-1} \left( \begin{array}{c} \Phi_1(x_j) \\ \Phi_2(x_j) \\ \vdots \\ \Phi_N(x_j)\end{array} \right) = e_j,   
$$
where $e_j$ is the $j$'th unit vector. Therefore $\Phi(x_j) = [y_{1}, \dots, y_N] \cdot e_j = y_j$ as desired.

**Remark:** The result only addresses the case of scalar outputs. However, the same result holds for multivariate outputs by putting networks in parallel.